# Javascript keyup not fired when stopping at a breakpoint for keydown

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, keyboard-events

I want to store the down keys in my application.
I do it in a way that I put the down keys into an array on keydown and remove them on keyup.

Now the problem occurs when I debug with breakpoints, which stops after the keydown but before the keyup. The keyup never runs and my down keys will be registered forever breaking the logic of my app.

Pseudo code for explanation:

```
<html>
    <script>
        const keys = new Set();

        window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
            keys.add(e.keyCode)
            debugger; // the app stops at this breakpoint when developer tools is open 
        });

        window.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
            keys.delete(e.keyCode) // this does not run when stopping at breakpoint
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

How would you ensure that `keys` Set always reflects the keys which are actually down.

Comment: Quoting https://crbug.com/542356: Unfortunately, we can't do anything here. Pausing in keydown swallows next keypress and keyup events and input doesn't get the char. This is a common limitation of sequenced events (e.g. mousedown/up/click or touchstart/move/end). A possible workaround is to add "keypress" listeners instead of "keydown".

Comment: when you have set a breakpoint, you are essentially stopping any more javascript code from being executed. So, the keyup listener could never be triggered! The problem should be tackled in some other way. Why are you adding debugger anyway ?

Comment: Adding the debugger was just an example. I was debugging my app, and it is annoying that after returning from the breakpoint the app won't be in a consistent state anymore. But I understand your answer, maybe I need some workaround here.